# Doubly linked list delete even numbers in C++

Tags: c++, delete-operator, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to delete all even numbers from a doubly linked list.

I've considered the cases as:

1. empty list
2. even number at beginning,
3. even number at the end
4. even number in the middle of the list
5. even number not in the list

My code below won't work properly:

```
void DoublyList::deleteEvens()
{

    if (first == NULL) {
        cerr << "Empty List" << endl;
    }


    else {
        Node *current = first;
        bool found = false;
        while (current != NULL && (!found)) {
            Node *tCurrent = current;
            if (current->getNextLink() == NULL) {
                if (current->getData() % 2 == 0) {
                    first = NULL;
                    last = NULL;
                    delete current;
                    current = NULL;
                    count = 0;
                }
                else {
                    cerr << "Not in the list" << endl;
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            else if (current == first && current->getData() % 2 == 0) {
                first = first -> getNextLink();
                first->setPreviousLink(NULL);
                current = current->getNextLink();
                delete tCurrent;
                tCurrent = NULL;
                -- count;
            }
            else if (current == last && current->getData() % 2 == 0) {
                last = last->getPreviousLink();
                last->setNextLink(NULL);
                delete current;
                current = NULL;
                -- count;
            }

            else if (current->getData() % 2 == 0) {
                current->getPreviousLink()->setNextLink(current->getNextLink());
                current->getNextLink()->setPreviousLink(current->getPreviousLink());
                current = current->getNextLink();
                delete tCurrent;
                tCurrent = NULL;
            }
            else {
                current = current->getNextLink();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _'My below won't work properly.'_ is too vague question ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm just started learning programming, and I don't know how to be specific since the code some times works and some times doesn't...

Comment: Since this is a school project, you shouldn't get code.  But here's how to solve it-  break it into parts.  First write a function that can delete an item in a doubly linked list.  Then test it.  Then write a function to walk the list and find all even numbers.  Test it.  Then combine the two.  Don't try to do it as one massive step.

Comment: @ProgrammingLearning - Why reinvent the wheel - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/?kw=list . Could be done in one line using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove_if/

Comment: @Yu Hao, why did you delete my thanks twice????? Just want to be polite. Does "Thank you for your input" really hurt the format of the question?

Comment: Yes, adding thanks to posts is nothing but noise to the people reading them. The way to say thanks in SO is to post good posts, and upvote the posts that's helpful to you. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) on Meta.

Comment: @YuHao Read the comments please. Lots of peoples against this idea. See this comment here -  "If you edit a post to remove a "thank you", it probably just means that you, the editor, have poor manners."

Comment: Please don't edit your question just to add thanks any more. It's a community policy in SO, respect it. Your editing only drags more people reading this already well answered question. That's a waste of time for them. I was just trying to improve the format on your post. If you don't think that's helpful to you, it's OK. But I won't take time on this a little meaningless arguing about whether to add thanks to a post. If you do like to argue about it, involve yourself in Meta to discuss it.

Comment: @YuHao So please stop deleting my thanks. Thank you for trying to help, although I'm sorry I don't think your editing is at all helpful to me or ANYONE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be your first case: `current->getNextLink() == NULL` will evaluate to true for that last item in the list. So, when you process the last item, you effectively delete the entire list.

I assume this is meant to detect the first item in the list, change it to:

`if (current->getNextLink() == NULL && current->getPreviousLink() == NULL)`

or, alternatively, move it outside the loop and just use the first variable.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH! IT TOTALLY WORKS NOW! :)

Comment: @ProgrammingLearning - please become friends with STL. Saves so much time

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for the suggestion, I just started learning and will explore more! Thank you for your input!